# How to query out the first time series data and filter the null values in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have three time series and I want to query the first time series data and filter out the null values in Apache IoTDB. I tried query statement: `select first value(*) from root.maas .CPEC1.LFPa1.L6FE-R1G3901-'.ACEOPTALRT.** WHERE time >= 1691647554774 AND time <= 1691736654623 without null all(first value(AlertID),first value(AlertReset)) align by device`, but IoTDB returned an error: `SOL Error [700] [Error occurred while parsing SOL to physical plan: line 2:54 no viable alternative`. Seems like I did not write the statement correctly, so anyone know how should I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `having fist_value(AlertID) IS NOT NULL` in command of Apache IoTDB to only keep the first not-null query value.